# Why is the SMTP AUTH extension sometimes advertised as AUTH=<SASL>?

Tags: email, authentication, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm investigating an issue with SMTP AUTH, and I noticed that some mail servers advertise support for AUTH like this:

```
$ telnet myhost.com 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myhost.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 myhost.com ESMTP service ready
ehlo there
250-myhost.com says hello
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH CRAM-MD5
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5
250-SIZE 100000000
250 DSN
```

I expected something like:

```
250-AUTH CRAM-MD5
```

but I didn't expect:

```
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5
```

I've read RFC 4954 and some of the associated RFCs, but I didn't see an example with the "=" sign.  Can someone tell me why this variant syntax exists, and where it is documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not all clients recognize the AUTH capability as defined by the SASL authentication RFC. Some historical implementations expect the server to send an "=" as separator between the AUTH verb and the list of mechanisms that follows it.

The "broken" clients include Outlook up to and including version 2003 and Outlook Express up to version 6.

See http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_authc